# HTML File Upload - Practical Limit?

Tags: html, file-upload

We are designing an internal web application to which we would like to upload a very large file (100mb).  Is an HTML file upload even an option here?

If it is not, what other tools (Java applet, Silverlight, Flash) could we use to perform a file upload this large?  Is uploading a file this large practical at all?

**Edit:** You can assume that there will be appropriate server side code accepting the file upload and handling the data.  This question is specifically about the client side interface and the HTML file upload interface.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053290/large-file-upload-though-html-form-more-than-2-gb/10845664#10845664

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on file uploading, but my understanding is it's either impossible or very difficult to upload a file with HTML alone. You will probably need some server-side scripting like PHP, JSP, ASP.NET or something to process the upload and persist the file on your web server/database. Any well-designed implementation should allow for a size limit to be set and enforced, but with larger files it would be a good idea to include a progress indicator like a percentage and/or progress bar so the user knows the upload is still working and isn't hanging on slow connections.

I just downloaded this UploadBean component and deployed the WAR under the downloads section on an apache tomcat instance and the SimpleUpload.jsp example worked really well right out of the box. If you're using Java I'd highly recommend this approach.

http://www.javazoom.net/jzservlets/uploadbean/uploadbean.html

Answer (score 0):

with javascript/jQuery/Mootools/Flash there are plugins that allows you to check file size before upload, and basically has server side script as fallback validation as well.  Take a look at [jQuery Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [Mootools powered fancy upload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)  they use flash and javascript with server side script in the backend.  These two plugins use flash + JavaScript on client side

Comment: The problem is some of those tools, such as Uploadify, limit the size to 100Mb.  Does your comment on the answer below indicate that fancy upload works better?

Comment: @CRoss i use it and it works fine so far for me and usually the people that work on it are on #Mootools freenodes IRC so support is awesome too.

Answer (score 0):

Being that it will be for an internal web application I am assuming you don't have any server-side imposed limits on the server that will be running this. If not then you should be able to upload large files.

See http://www.uploadify.com/ - nice and easy to implement

See http://encodable.com/filechucker/ - good if you are looking for more advanced management for your uploaded files.

Comment: I was under the impression uploadify had a hard limit of 100Mb, is this not the case?

Comment: Yes actually I believe that is correct. Forgot about that. I believe the 100mb limit is due to a limit in Flash which uploadify uses.

Comment: http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/ scroll down to filesize max here is the sentence: `fileSizeMax: (number: defaults to 0) Validates the maximal size of a selected file (official limit is 100 MB for FileReference, I tested up to 2 GB)`