# Uploading files of 1GB or more

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

What is the best way to upload files larger than 1 GB?

Current Situation :: We're using flask to deploy webserver. We have to upload files larger than 1 GB. Previously we only uploaded few mbs of files. So, it wasn't a problem but now with files larger than 1 GB the old method of upload is not possible. The server just timeout.

So is there a good way to upload files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053290/large-file-upload-though-html-form-more-than-2-gb

Comment: thank you 
so there is limitation

Answer (score 1):

you need to configure MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH to be at least 1 GB (maybe add more for padding).

```
from flask import Flask, Request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
```

Comment: that would only solve the file size problem
is there a better way to upload files of that size?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the web is over the HTTP protocol, so whatever method you use is over HTTP. WebDAV allows bi-directional file access, which IMO is overkill since you said you only want users to upload files, not read or edit them, it's no different (speed/reliability wise) than doing a regular PUT or POST request. You could look into FTP, but the consensus on that is other than implied access control, HTTP vs FTP uploads are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using WebDAV (PUT) over HTTP using one of the Python DAV libraries. I personally use TinyDAV library to do this. Not sure on max file size, but I upload > 1GB files using this. It is probably configurable on the DAV server side (mod_dav with Apache).

http://code.google.com/p/tinydav/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dav.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Comment: Thanx
this seems to be thing we're looking after 
we'll give it a try