# Upload large file in php and show error

Tags: php, upload

When I upload a file which is less than 500MB on a server using PHP, then it uploads perfectly. But when I try to upload above 500MB (like 550MB or 700MB) then it shows error.

My php.ini settings are below

```
upload_max_filesize=2048M 
post_max_size=2048M
max_execution_time=3000 (50 minutes)
memory_limit=1024M
```

I have tried debugging and I found out something

After the file upload I checked the temp path of the file with this function `!file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])` and it returned true, and when I uploaded less than 500MB then returned false and file was uploaded successfully.
I'm using amazon web server it's specifications are
- 4GB RAM.
- 2 Processors.

I'm not sure where is the problem.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Did you check if your php.ini settings got applied? Just create a PHP file with this content `<?php phpinfo();`, and call it. It will show all settings.

Comment: By the way see the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053290/large-file-upload-though-html-form-more-than-2-gb  HTML5 can slice a big file into parts, and upload them separately. So this problem could be solved by involving the frontend developer.

Comment: Occur this error while uploading above 500MB file UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE (Failed to write file to disk.) when i use error handling using this parameter of file $_FILES['file_name']['error']. I match the error with php manual php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Try to check the available disk space: http://php.net/manual/en/function.disk-free-space.php
Or contact the support of amazon. Maybe there's a file size limit.